# Postback in Website and webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web

I'm confused on how the postback works in website and web application because,

I have a button and in that I have given a sleep time for about 30 seconds and in another page on the same time when I try to do any activities like, click redirect etc.

In Web application the above scenario works without any issue.

In Web Site till the button event comes out the sleep time all the other activities will be hang up.

Please explain me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess there is only one thread maintaining website.. In ASP.NET if `Session` is enabled requests (within session) are processed one by one until you specify special attribute on page.

Comment: Is there any alternate to overcome this problem in website ?

Comment: Check if WebApplication and WebSite are using `Session` state by default

Comment: I have added session state in webconfig. mode="InProc" timeout="20"

Answer (score 1):

If `Session` state is enabled, requests within the session will be processed one by one. In your case, request is not completed until button handler comes out of sleep. Other requests are waiting until first request is completed.

To enable concurrent requests you must specify `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"` in ASPX file which contains button. Or just disable `Session` state in webconfig.

```
<%@ Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" MasterPageFile="..." CodeBehind="xxx.cs" Inherits="xxx" %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have configured in webconfig file and it is working fine. Could I know if there are any other impacts by adding this attribute ?

Comment: If you set `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"` on the page you must understand that `Session` dictionary is accessible from other pages and you have to maintain concurrency.

Comment: How to maintain concurrency ? This is working on the project I am using for testing. likes just 2 pages in it and 1 buttons in each page. When I add this in our main project then I'm not able to login to my application itself. It doesn't redirect to other page after successful login. If I remove this attribute it is working.